# How to move a file into an output folder as soon as it is inserted into an input folder using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Using the below code to create a camel route, but when files are created in source, no impact appears in test. Why?

```
public class DriverMain {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("file://source").to("file://test");
            }
        });


        context.start();
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\source";
        File dir = new File(path);
        File file = new File(path+"\\testfile.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should also stop the context at the end. Add a context.stop() as the final row. Also, the from() and to() are reading from a relative folder. You are sure that your app is running under user.dir/source?

Answer (score 0):

Camel polls for files on a regular basis.  You're creating a file, but then ending the application immediately, not leaving any time for Camel to poll for your file.  By default, Camel waits 1000 milliseconds before it starts polling.  You can see the options for the [file2 component here](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html).

In this test you need to add a `Thread.sleep(2000)` after you create the file.  Or better yet, start camel running as a standalone process, and kill it when the test is over yourself.  You can do that by using the `org.apache.camel.main.Main` class.  There's examples of running [Camel standalone here](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html).